# How can I authenticate with Google Play Services when using Realtime Database's API?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a mobile game in Unity and using a Firebase Realtime Database for online leaderboards.

A pre-requisite for playing my game is the user logging into Google Play Services (Integrated into Unity using the official SDK), so I want my code to use the user's Google Play Services account to authenticate with my DB.

I know that authentication via Google Play Services is possible, but my questions are:

1. Can one authenticate using Google Play Services when using the REST API? If so, what is the structure of such a query?
2. What rules/configuration do I need to set up on the Firebase Realtime Database side to allow all read/writes from authenticated users and deny all anonymous operations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth?

Comment: This explains how to authenticate via Access Tokens or Firebase IDs, but not via Google Play Services accounts.
Just to clarify - are you perhaps proposing that I check on-client if the user signed in to Google Play Services, and if so use a service account's access token to authenticate against Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer, thanks in part to [Patrick Matrin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043663/patrick-martin)'s response.

> Can one authenticate using Google Play Services when using the REST API? If so, what is the structure of such a query?

The answer is yes, it is possible, but it's not straightforward.

In order to add authentication to requests, an access token is required.
The syntax change is quite simple, so let's say the URL you were originally posting to was:

`https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/<SUB_FOLDER>/<SUB_FOLDER2>.json`

You will want to change it to:

`https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/<SUB_FOLDER>/<SUB_FOLDER2>.json?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_access_token).

The main issue is getting that Access Token. To grossly over-simplify, what you want to do is the following:

1. Start Google Play Services in your game
2. Authenticate user with Google Play Services (have them 'log in')
3. Swap out the authentication code we got for an access token

Steps 1 and 2 should be fairly straightforward, and you probably already did them if you're using Google Play Services. In any case, this is how the class looks in my project:

```
public class GPGSAuthentication : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayGamesPlatform platform;

    void Start()
    {
        if (platform == null)
        {
            PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().RequestServerAuthCode(false).Build();
            PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
            PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

            platform = PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        }

        Social.Active.localUser.Authenticate(success =>
        {
            if (success)
            {
                Debug.Log("GSPS - Logged in successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("GSPS - Falied to login");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Notice the use of RequestServerAuthCode(false) in the config build. You'll need this if you want to get the Authentication Code discussed earlier.

After that, you'll need to use REST API in order to exchange the auth code for an access token. You'll need to query a GoogleAPI URL and supply some parameters:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Trades the auth code for a Google Access Token.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientID">The ID of the client we're trying to reach</param>
    /// <param name="clientSecret">The secret of the client we're trying to reach</param>
    /// <param name="grantType">The grant_type value</param>
    /// <param name="authCode">The auth code we want to trade in for the Google Access Token</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEnumerator GetAccessToken(string clientID, string clientSecret, string grantType, string authCode)
    {
        if (googleAccessToken != null && googleAccessToken != "")
        {
            Debug.Log("Not requesting googleAccessToken again since we already have it");
            yield break;
        }

        //googleAccessToken = "";
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("client_id", clientID);
        form.AddField("client_secret", clientSecret);
        form.AddField("grant_type", grantType);
        form.AddField("code", authCode);

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", form);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Ran into error while trying to get access token\n Error: " + www.error + "\nURL: " + www.url.ToString() + "\nCode: " + authCode);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Got Access Token in return, full string is: \n" + www.downloadHandler.text);
            GoogleData googleData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GoogleData>(www.downloadHandler.text);
            googleAccessToken = googleData.access_token;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class for handling data received from Google after giving Auth Code
    /// </summary>
    [System.Serializable]
    public class GoogleData
    {
        public string access_token;
        public string token_type;
        public int expires_in;
        public string refresh_token;
    }
```

You'll need to get the values for `client_id` and `client_secret` from your OAuth2 web client that you created. You should be able to read them in the Google API credentials page.

As for `grant_type`, always supply the value `"authorization_code"`, and in order to get the value of your Authentication Code, use `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode()`, though obviously only after successfully logging in the user in Google Play Services.

Now you should have everything needed to authenticate your user with Firebase using Google Play Services. No further SDK or package/plugin needed.

> What rules/configuration do I need to set up on the Firebase Realtime Database side to allow all read/writes from authenticated users and deny all anonymous operations?

Patrick's answer here was correct. This is a simple rule with the following syntax:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "node_to_protect": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null",
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I'll apologize by not answering the question directly but by trying to answer the spirit of the question. Since you are using Realtime Database and Firebase Authentication, it's worth pointing out that as long as you're building a mobile game (iOS/Android) you're best off using the [official Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup). Since desktop support is beta, other platforms aren't there (consoles, web, &c), and some devs prefer not to use native plugins feel free to vote the answer down due to this initial caveat.

With that out of the way, first I'll point out that there is an [example online leaderboard](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/unity-solutions/tree/master/Firebase_Leaderboard) you can pull directly into your project that uses the Realtime Database Unity SDK.

I'd recommend following [this video](https://youtu.be/52yUcKLMKX0) to get started, and [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/google-signin) for how to auth using Google Sign-in. But you'll generally do something like:

```
// make sure you've finished CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync before this
var auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;

// sign in credentials persist between runs, make sure you're not already signed in
if (auth.CurrentUser == null) {
  Firebase.Auth.Credential credential =
      Firebase.Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken);
  auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
    if (task.IsCanceled) {
      Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
      return;
    }
    if (task.IsFaulted) {
      Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
      return;
    }

    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
    Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
        newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
  });
}
```

I know that the docs are a little sparse here, but `googleIdToken` should come from the Google Sign In plugin and the access token looks like it can be null. To pull one more piece of google documentation, [this is a sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity#using-this-plugin-with-firebase-auth) for how to use google sign in. So:

```
    GoogleSignIn.Configuration = new GoogleSignInConfiguration {
      RequestIdToken = true,
      // Copy this value from the google-service.json file.
      // oauth_client with type == 3
      WebClientId = "1072123000000-iacvb7489h55760s3o2nf1xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    };

    GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
        var idToken = ((Task<GoogleSignInUser>)task).Result.IdToken;
        // create the Firebase credential now.
    });
```

Now for rules, I'm going to assume that you're using the [Realtime Database Unity SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start). If you use this SDK and the Firebase Auth one, your user credentials will automatically get propagated to Realtime Database for you. In that case, what you want to do is [a pretty common use case](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#structuring_your_database_to_support_authentication_conditions).

So if you just want to require authentication to read and write to a part of the database:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "node_to_protect": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null",
        }
    }
}
```

Note that Realtime Database's security validator will not accept just `auth != null` as security, but that will get you started.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thank you for your detailed response.
Since I've not been able to successfully set up all the packages and plugins you mentioned (Google Sign In, Realtime Database Unity SDK), I've yet to confirm if this would work for me or not, though I guess it'll be fine.

Still, as you said this doesn't answer my base question - is it possible to authenticate via Google Play Services specifically? This uses the generic Google Sign In and not Google Play Services for auth.
Likewise, this doesn't use the REST API so it means I'll have to change my approach.