# Firebase Realtime Database returns 401 when trying to authenticate?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using REST API in my app to communicate with a Firebase RTDB, and trying to use a Google Access Token to authenticate my requests.

My issue is that with even the most permissive Rules on the database, I get HTTP error 401 in response to queries that try to authenticate.

For example, say I try to put some data in my database with the following command, I get 401 in return (all the values within < > are placeholders):

`curl -XPUT -d '{  "UserID" : "<GOOGLE_UID>",  "UserName" : "Clicksurfer",  "CompletionMoves" : 8,  "CompletionTime" : 16.21979  }' https://<FIREBASE_URL>.firebaseio.com/Level2/<GOOGLE_UID>.json/?access_token=<GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN>`

`401`

The strangest part is, when I abandon the use of access token altogether the query works:

`curl -XPUT -d '{  "UserID" : "<GOOGLE_UID>",  "UserName" : "Clicksurfer",  "CompletionMoves" : 8,  "CompletionTime" : 16.21979  }' https://<FIREBASE_URL>.firebaseio.com/Level2/<GOOGLE_UID>.json`

`200`

As I said, I am currently using the most permissive rules for debugging:

```
{
    "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT:**

I use the [Google Play Games plugin for Unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) in my project, among other things to get the AuthCode.

In order to do this, I needed to do a couple of things:

1. When building the config for Google Play Games during startup, I made sure to call the `RequestServerAuthCode(false)` method
2. Have the user login after Google Play Games sets up
3. Make sure that the relevant ClientID was supplied to Unity (in this case, it is a web client that has auth permissions on my Firebase rtdb).

This all looks like this:

```
public class GPGSAuthentication : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayGamesPlatform platform;

    void Start()
    {
        if (platform == null)
        {
            PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().RequestServerAuthCode(false).Build();
            PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
            PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

            platform = PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        }

        Social.Active.localUser.Authenticate(success =>
        {
            if (success)
            {
                Debug.Log("GSPS - Logged in successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("GSPS - Falied to login");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Note ClientID is supplied]

Now that we've done this, we can call `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode()` in order to get the AuthCode.

I traded in my AuthCode for an Access Token by sending a POST request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`. In my query, I supply 4 fields:

- `client_id`, which has the ID of the previously used client (where we got the AuthCode from).
- `client_secret`, which has the correlating secret.
- `grant_type`, which is always with the value `"authorization_code"`
- `code`, which has the value of the AuthCode we got.

In response, I get a `200` response with 4 parameters:

- `access_token`, the token I (fail to) use when authenticating against my Firebase rtdb.
- `token_type`, the type of the aforementioned token.
- `expires_in`, the amount of time before the token expires (I presume in seconds unit)
- `refresh_token`, a token which can be used in order to get a new `access_token` without having to keep the Google user connected.

I then supply this `access_token` value to the queries I send to my DB, and promptly get the `401` error.

Comment: It seems that your access token is not valid. How do you generate it?

Comment: Hi Frank,

I generate the Access Token by trading in an Auth Code that I get from Google Play Services after a user authenticates with it (logs in).

To see the full process that I do, please [check out my answer on this exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65168293/how-can-i-authenticate-with-google-play-services-when-using-realtime-databases). I use the Google Play Services package for Unity and do everything else via REST API.

Comment: "that I get from Google Play Services" sounds a bit suspicious. Can you show the code of how you determine the exact value you pass in for `GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN`?

Comment: No worries, @FrankvanPuffelen

I edited my original post because there was a lot of info to supply - please check eveything under the **edit** section. Thanks :)

Comment: Is that access token an OAuth2 token? And if so, is that user a collaborator on the project? Because for regular (non collaborator) users, you should always authenticate with an ID token as far as I know.

Comment: I gotta admit that I am unsure about both of these things.

For the first question, I believe it is an OAuth2 token since it behaves just like an OAuth2 token should, but as far as I know these tokens don't have a predefined structure so I'm unsure.

For example, here is a return value I got a few days ago: `ya29.a0AfH6SMA38GUpDHu27STdb6fV3u2tZadcLRMInvrydJf-0mF-vvdswlc1OxwhtvHKqBHqmI1HujXvHi4h4S79mZT2jmp15g1Ng_zx8cBFznnv0bdLAj9VHiJp9YrBnoIzPInAhpxI_5tjQw8ENLE1z1YvtRSonD6_6Ntr-gwFRlzn
`

Comment: As for collaborator user, I am also unsure. This is an OAuth 2.0 client defined in the Google API console, and its `Client ID` and `Client Secret` are configured in the Firebase dashboard under `Authentication`->`Sign-in method`->`Play Games`.

Is this incorrect behavior? Please advise.

Comment: That's definitely an OAuth2 token, and not a JWT, which means it's only going to be accepted by the database if its for either a collaborator or a service account on the project. I'm not sure you can use this OAuth token with RTDB as is. Did you read anywhere that this should work?

Comment: I understood [from the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_access_token) that this was a valid way of using RTDB, but I guess I understood incorrectly :)

So you're saying the correct way for me to have users use Google Play Games creds to access RTDB is via a Firebase ID Token?

If so, do you know how I can get an ID Token using only REST API? [The documentation I found](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web) only uses plugins and packages, and my app is too bloated for them unfortunately.

Comment: 1) As far as I know the OAuth tokens need to belong to either a service account or a collaborator on the project. Otherwise: how would Firebase know that the token is allowed to make changes? I might be wrong of course, but in that case at the very least I expect that the token needs to have the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and 
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database` scopes as shown in that first documentation link. 2) You can only generate ID tokens for Firebase Authentication users.